# print the most common value from sql

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, count

I have a list of words in an SQLite database and I want to get the most common value and save it in a variable.I am using python3 
here is how I got my most common value.

```
SELECT emotion,
     COUNT(emotion) AS value_occurrence 
FROM     chatlog
GROUP BY emotion
ORDER BY value_occurrence DESC
LIMIT    1;
```

Comment: So are you asking for some Python code?  Your query looks fine (under certain assumptions).

Comment: I am asking if there is a way to get the value in a variable for example if I have [happy, sad, angry, happy]. I want it to save the word [happy] in a variable [X]. If there is a way you know then I would be delighted to have a code or an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be something like this?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('yourdb')

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('''SELECT emotion,
     COUNT(emotion) AS value_occurrence 
     FROM   chatlog
     GROUP BY emotion
     ORDER BY value_occurrence DESC
     LIMIT    1''')

rows = cur.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        x = row[0]
        y = row[1]
        print(x,y)
```